# Removing dashes, spaces and adding dashes again after every 3 digits

Tags: php

I want to remove spaces, and dashes from $S and then include dashes after every 3 digits in the string.

`00-44  48 5555 8361` should convert to `004-448-555-583-61`

`0 - 22 1985--324` should convert to `022-198-53-24`

`555372654` should convert to `555-372-654`

Right now, `substr_replace()` works weirdly.

Here is my code,

```
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// print "this is a debug message\n";
function solution($S) {
    // write your code in PHP5.5
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '{ }';
    $patterns[1] = '{-}';
    $number = preg_replace($patterns, "", $S);
    //echo $number;

     for($i=3; $i<strlen($number); $i=$i+4){
           $number = substr_replace($number,"-", $i, 0);
     }
     return $number;




}
```

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('#[0-9]{3}([- ]+)#', '', $string);` ?

Comment: Why isn't it `022-198-532-4`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: What I mentioned is the requirement.

Comment: OK but it doesn't agree with the example.

Comment: @FahadUddin If the requirement is `022-198-53-24` you haven't given us the right rules to implement. You stated "include dashes after every 3 digits in the string" but gave an example that puts dashes after **two** digits.

Comment: @FahadUddin You had this question deleted, then reopened it without modifications. The issues with it remain.

Comment: I had a discussion with the person who posted answer on the question on email and we agreed back to displaying this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert the hyphens easily with [chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php). It inserts one extra one at the end though, so you'll want to use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to remove it:

```
$str = '00-44  48 5555 8361';
$result = rtrim( chunk_split( preg_replace( '/[- ]/', '', $str ), 3, '-' ), '-' );
// '004-448-555-583-61'
```

**Edit:**

To solve the last case where you want the end of the number to be `wx-yz` instead of `wxy-z` you can use this:

```
if ( strlen( $result ) % 4 === 1 )
    $result  = preg_replace( '/(\d)-(\d)$/', '-$1$2', $result );
```

Comment: @FahadUddin You said "include dashes after every 3 digits in the string".

Comment: @FahadUddin You said you want to include dashes after every three digits. A dash after `53` would only be after two digits.

Comment: @FahadUddin I've flagged your question for a moderator's attention. They should swing by and delete it.